# If $|a_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{n+p}|<\epsilon$ than \sum a_n converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\epsilon>0$. Prove that there is $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
if $|a_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{n+p}|<\epsilon\; \forall n>n_0,p\geq 1 \Rightarrow \sum a_n$ converges.

What I had in mind was 
$$|a_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{n+p}| = \left|\sum^{n+p}_{i=1}a_n-\sum^{n}_{i=1}a_n\right|\leq \epsilon$$

But then I don't know how to find a way to show that $\sum a_n$ is convergent. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate tells you that the sequence of partial sums of the series is a [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence).